# Gulp saving stream preserving directory structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, gulp

I have a plugin that generates new files in the stream using this function

```
var pass = through2.obj(function (file, enc, callback) {
        if (!gulpmatch(file, __json_condition)) {
            this.push(file);
        }else {
            compiled_files = bootsie_compiler.build_from_buffer(file.contents, {stream:true});
            for (var i =0; i<compiled_files.length; i++){
                this.push(new gutil.File(
                    {
                        base: compiled_files[i].base,
                        path: compiled_files[i].path,
                        contents: new Buffer(compiled_files[i].contents)
                    })
                );
            }

        }
        callback();
    });
```

Everything works as expected and gulp-filelogs outputs 3 files in the stream

```
[21:51:34] [1] [Path:/home/michael/Projects/OpenSource/Portfolio/www/build/index.html]   [Base:/home/michael/Projects/OpenSource/Portfolio/www/build] [CWD:/home/michael/Projects/OpenSource/Portfolio/www]
[21:51:34] [2] [Path:/home/michael/Projects/OpenSource/Portfolio/www/build/archive/test/index.html] [Base:/home/michael/Projects/OpenSource/Portfolio/www/build/archive/test] [CWD:/home/michael/Projects/OpenSource/Portfolio/www]
[21:51:34] [3] [Path:/home/michael/Projects/OpenSource/Portfolio/www/build/archive/test2/index.html] [Base:/home/michael/Projects/OpenSource/Portfolio/www/build/archive/test2] [CWD:/home/michael/Projects/OpenSource/Portfolio/www]
```

My gulp task is this one

```
gulp.task("bootsie-build",["copy-assets"], function(){
    var build_dir = "./build";
    var src_dir = "./src";

    return gulp.src([src_dir+"/website.json"]) //Configuration file parsed
        .pipe(bootsie.build())  // function that generates the 3 files
        .pipe(filelog())        // filelog, outputs the 3 lines above
        .pipe(gulp.dest(build_dir))   //Save files
}
```

My problem is that the structure is not preserved so I have in this case

```
./build/index.html
```

That contains the last file saved (the other two are overwritten),
Instead of

```
./build/index.html
./build/test/index.html
./build/test2/index.html
```

How do I preserve the structure?